# При отправке формы пустая страница post.php и не приходит письмо на почту

Tags: php, sendmail

**При отправке формы пустая страница post.php и не приходит письмо на почту**

Кнопка заказать [сайт](http://i-vipmarket.ru/power-bank.html)

файл post.php

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <?
    $send = $_POST['button'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($send == "button"){

        $to = "difkaskon@gmail.com";                 // <- Ваша почта
        $subject = "Письмо с сайта";        // <- Тема письма на почте
        $mailheaders .="От: $email";

        $msg .= "ФИО отправителя: $name\r\n";
        $msg .= "Телефон: $email\r\n";

        var_dump (mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders));

        $mess= "Уважаемый $name, ваше сообщение было успешно отправленно.";

        echo '<center><p class="text">' . $mess ;

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Собственно, я не вижу вызова функции `mail`, только его `var_dump`. Вам надо убрать вашу кодировку из файла `post.php` и попробовать ещё раз.

Comment: Да, и на всякий случай, `var_dump` тоже надо убрать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данных вы дали недостаточно, где форма например сама (проблема как раз в том, как вы ее отправяете), но думаю по этому примеру все поймете:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (!empty($name) AND !empty($email)){

    $to = "difkaskon@gmail.com";        
    $subject = "Письмо с сайта";      
    $mailheaders .="От: $email";

    $msg .= "ФИО отправителя: $name\r\n";
    $msg .= "Телефон: $email\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders)) {
        $mess = "Уважаемый $name, ваше сообщение было успешно отправленно.";
    } else {
        $mess = "Ошибка при отправке.";
    }

   echo $mess;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <button type="submit">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
```